# BokehJS import not working properly in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bokeh, create-react-app, bokehjs

I'm trying to use the plotting library BokehJS with a React app that was set up using

```
create-react-app myapp
```

The library was installed using

```
npm install bokehjs
```

Inside the myapp/public/index.html file, the following lines were added (as explained in the user guide's [installation section](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/installation.html#installation)):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-api-1.4.0.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-api-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

I now would like to recreate some of the [examples](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/bokehjs.html#userguide-bokehjs) in the BokehJS user guide. Importing the module in myapp/App.js with

```
import Bokeh from 'bokehjs'
```

gives no errors. But if I now try to access some of the module's functions/objects like

```
Bokeh.Plot()
```

or

```
Bokeh.LinAlg
```

the following error is displayed in the browser after compilation:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'bokehjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a.LinAlg')
```

Any help with fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The console in the browser's developer tools also displays the following error, when the scripts are included in the html file:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `bokeh-1.4.0` instead of `bokeh-1.14.0` in your `script` links.

Further as far as `css` links are concerned: 
Copying and pasting http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.css and http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-api-1.4.0.min.cssin the browser gives an error so it looks like those files don't exist. As far as I know you don't need those files anymore (as of Bokeh v1.3.0).

See also [this discussion](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/cdn-css-files-returns-empty-list-in-bokeh-1-3-4/3894) on Discourse.

But if you really need them  you could use:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bokeh/1.2.0/bokeh.css 
and 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bokeh/1.2.0/bokeh.min.css

or

https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.2.0.min.css
and
https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.2.0.css

Comment: I'm sorry, I messed that up when writing the question. I am actually using version 1.4.0 in my index.html, the problem still persists. The question has been updated.

Comment: You actually don't need the `css` files anymore (see updated answer).

Comment: Ok, I did not know that. But I don't think the problem has anything to do with the css files. Whether or not I have them in my index.html file, I get a TypeError when trying to access the page.

Comment: Put only `script` links in your code, clear your browser catch and try `console.log(Bokeh)`. What does it say? But I see that actually `import Bokeh from 'bokehjs'` is giving a problem

Comment: Check [this page](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/bokehjs.html#userguide-bokehjs). It says that you should also import `bokeh-api.js ` **after**  importing the core BokehJS library.

Comment: `console.log(Bokeh)`  does not lead to an error message. There are two error messages displayed though regarding the script tags. They say `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()`

Comment: As you can see in my original post, I have actually imported the bokeh-api script after bokeh.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202582/discussion-between-pfincent-and-tony).

Answer (score 0):

I am running create-react-app React 16.12, NPM 6.13.6, Bokeh 2.0, ES6 and this worked for me:

- Installed BokehJS using `npm install @bokeh/bokehjs`
- In the module where I want to embed the Bokeh plot: `import { embed } from '@bokeh/bokehjs';`
- To embed the plot after receiving a response from an Axios get request: `embed.embed_item(response.data, 'myplot');` and include the JSX `<div id='myplot' className="bk-root"></div>` at the desired location.